# SharePoint 2010 could not create custom subsite of type publishing site

Tags: sharepoint

I'm stuck with a SharePoint 2010 exception when trying to create a subsite with a custom template of type publishing site:

```
Provisioning did not succeed.  Details: Failed to initialize some site properties for web "http://site/subWeb"
Original Exception: Value does not fall within expected range..
Stacktrace: at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleCOMException(COMException comEx)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplates(...)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(string strWebTemplate)
at Microsoft SharePoint.SPWeb.CreateWeb(...)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.Add(...)
at [custom code]
```

The error occurred approximately 10-15 seconds after the site creation process started.  I checked the logs, and the newly add-ed site was deleted after the activation of the Publishing feature failed.  I also found more detailed logging error in the log a bit earlier than the above:

```
Exception thrown when attempting to activate sub web's publishing feature:
attempting to get GUID from Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.QueryBasedCollection'1.get_Item(Guid uniqueId)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AcreaProvisioner.SetDefaultPageProperties(PublishingWeb area, Boolean& updateRequired)
```

I have no ideas why a GUID is involved when activating a sub web's publishing feature...

The web template comes from SharePoint 2007, but I'm not sure whether there are anything special that needs to be applied to it before it will work properly in 2010 (assume not).

Things I have tried so far: re-activating all server publishing feature in all scopes + iisreset with all possible combinations, but nothing worked so far.

Desperately need some help on this one... TIA.

Answer (score 0):

In 2010 from my experience you can't create custom site templates of type publishing without fudging around a little and i'm sure theres good reason Check this thread out

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgenerallegacy/thread/b14e572a-ea17-47b4-93fe-4694451efe35

Now for possibly some bad news

This thread doesn't answer your question exactly but sort of gives advice about 2007 to 2010. The advice that the guy gives is to recreate and migrate the data and he has placed some tips at the bottom of his post.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/c912f1c6-9790-4216-a6b0-54bfb8a1459d

I hope this helps :)